# Printing Null Character ("\x00") in Python vs C

Tags: python, c, null, string-formatting

When I code and run the statement:

```
   print "\x00\x00\x00"
```

in Python it outputs three blank spaces followed by a newline. But in C, when I code and run the statement:

```
   char hex[] = "\x00\x00\x00";
   printf("%s\n", hex);
```

it interprets the NULL bytes like I thought it would: it doesn't do anything. So why in Python are NULL bytes treated as spaces?...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So why in Python are NULL bytes treated as spaces?

It's not. Your terminal/console is treating them like spaces. C just happens to stop at the first NUL, whereas Python outputs them. Try writing three NULs to stdout instead.