# Using NULL bytes in bash (for buffer overflow)

Tags: python, c, linux, bash

I programmed a little C program that is vulnerable to a buffer overflow. Everything is working as expected, though I came across a little problem now:

I want to call a function which lies on address `0x00007ffff7a79450` and since I am passing the arguments for the buffer overflow through the bash terminal (like this:

```
./a "$(python -c 'print "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\x50\x94\xA7\xF7\xFF\x7F\x00\x00"')" )
```

I get an error that the bash is ignoring the nullbytes.

```
/bin/bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

As a result I end up with the wrong address in memory (`0x7ffff7a79450`instead of`0x00007ffff7a79450`).

Now my question is: How can I produce the leading 0's and give them as an argument to my program?

Comment: with *another* program ...

Comment: `NULL` is a macro with a _null pointer constant_. Never use it for `char`. And there is no problem with your code. You intentional invoke undefined behaviour and that's exactly what you get. Case closed.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19229243/8051589) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10770953/8051589) on SO. The bash is handling null bytes as space.

Comment: You are trying to fix the problem in wrong place. Fix the little C program vulnerable to a buffer overflow.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski: It is his intention to make his program vulnerable to a buffer overflow, for training/demo purposes. He just want to parse the address of a function containing null bytes.

Comment: Don't. Use a tool such as [`xxd`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xxd/) (with -r option), pass it hexadecimal to decode and pipe its output where you want it. That will do away with the bash+arbitrary binary combination.

Comment: @Andre Kampling yes exactly. thanks I will check xxd out

Comment: @spectras: I think pipe won't work, because a pipe goes to stdin and is not passed as an argument. For his vulnerability he needs it as argument, doesn't he?

Comment: @Andre Kampling yeah. I need it as an argument. Tried to use xxd with xargs, but that didn't work either

Comment: @AndreKampling> written as such yes, but I assumed he could modify his vulnerable code to `read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 2*sizeof(buf))` instead of copying from an argument. Not to mention, `strcpy` won't work anyway because it will also stop when it sees a `\0` and won't copy the whole argument even if you manage to put NULs in it.

Comment: @spectras: Right but maybe he does not has the possibility to do that, because maybe he needs the address that he wants at the specific address where the arguments of the program are lie. For me it seems impossible to do that, because a bash' string will end where `\0` occurs, like the SO answers saying that I'm posted above..

Comment: @AndreKampling well since I made up my program to just play around with it, it is highly possible that I made it unsolvable (atleast when I need NULL bytes for padding). The reason I need that specific address is, because the system function lies on this address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a bold move and assert what you want to do is not possible in a POSIX environment, because of the way arguments are passed.

Programs are run using the [execve](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) system call.

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

There are a few other functions but all of them wrap execve in the end or use an extended system call with the properties that follow:

- Program arguments are passed using an array of NUL-terminated strings.

That means that when the kernel will take your arguments and put them aside for the new program to use, it will only read them up to the first NUL character, and discard anything that follows.

So there is no way to make your example work if it has to include nul characters. This is why I suggested reading from stdin instead, which has no such limitation:

```
char buf[256];
read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 2*sizeof(buf));
```

You would normally need to check the returned value of `read`. For a toy problem it should be enough for you to trigger your exploit. Just pipe your malicious input into your program.