# python concatenating \x00 as string

Tags: python, concatenation, ascii

I am trying to concatenate multiple values in a list, all of the string datatype.

The issue is whenever I encounter the return string \x00, even when it is stored as a string "\x00", the code stops doing whatever it does and finishes.

Below is the code:

```
example = [5, "HELLO", "\x00", "abc", "\x00", 5]
print(example)

test = []
for value in example:
    test.append(str(value))
print("".join(test))
```

and here is the output:

```
[5, 'HELLO', '\x00', 'abc', '\x00', 5]
5HELLO
```

as you can see, after "HELLO", everything after is not included.Is there a way to get around this?

Apologies for any misunderstandings that i may have, I am still learning this language.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Python3.7 Win10 https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTAr7.png What's your OS and Python version?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Why are there whitespace in your string? I cannot reproduce that, the nullchars are just ignored here. Is this platform/terminal dependent?

Comment: Python 3.8.2 Win10

Comment: @Forp where do you run your code, in an IDE? In a terminal/shell (cmd?)? Jupyter Notebook? Apparently the interpretaion of null characters depends on the program used. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770940/printing-null-character-x00-in-python-vs-c Apparently whatever you use to print the result decides to stop printing the string when encountering the null character.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa interesting! Might be platform dependent but I'd expect the null character to _not_ be represented as whitespace because it isn't whitespace.

Comment: It may well be IDE dependent (however that does not make sense to me and would appreciate and answer. Originally I was using IDLE just to test, but the code works fine in PyCharm. @JanChristophTerasa post that as an answer so I can mark it :)

Comment: what your python version is?

Comment: what're your see at idle `print("\x00")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printing of [null characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) in strings depends on the terminal/program being used, it might well be that your program/IDE stops printing a string when it encounters a null character, while other programs might print whitespaces or skip them. A similar question and answer can be found here: [Printing Null Character ("\x00") in Python vs C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770940/printing-null-character-x00-in-python-vs-c)